# NodeJS + Passport.js - no session stored?

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I have a problem with sessions in my app. I'm trying to learn Passport.js based on this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/ . What I want to do is to allow the acccess for only authenticated users. The process of login works great, but when I check if the user is authenticated, it always says not. What could go wrong?
Here is the checking function:

```
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
  return next();
else {
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

Here is the path from the router:

```
router.get('/secret', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to the secret page');
});
```

I didn't find any domunentation about how to check if the session was established, where it is and so on.

Comment: How do you check if the user isn't authenticated? Does it redirect you to / ?

Comment: yes, it simply redirects me to '/' and that is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, taken from passport.js documentation.

```
app.get('/secret', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
});
```

http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Comment: I have two questions: Do I need tu use Connect for this to work (something is mentioned in the Docs)? And secondly if I need to use serialize and deserializeUser for this to work? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This works for me, when I send the username and password overtime I am doing a request, but is it also possible to make this working with sessions, since this seems to be more secure for me?

Comment: My question on stackoverflow on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724707/passport-js-serializeuser-not-working-with-nsurlsession-on-ios